# Recursive does not listen to Return but Exit(0)

Tags: c

** Edit , Apologies, I just learnt that this is recursive. Apologies.

**Any advice on how i can make it work like a loop where I can return as **and when i want? or is my design very wrong?

I have the following loop that i Call, I personally want to call Next function and pass the previous "root" into the Tree

Problem i face now is when i return, it's being ignored but if i replace my return with exit(0); it stops, It just doesn't stop when i do a return.

By right if i'm right, return should stop the loop and directly return to the function that called it so that I can call NEXT when i want to.

Conclusion : As long as it hits return, the loop will repeat itself until the end of the Tree.

Objective : Loop next only when i call this function. I will return the current position of the node and put it back when i want the Next.

Any Advice?

```
struct item* loop(struct item *root)
{

   if(root != NULL){
      if(root->right != NULL) {
          loop(root->right);
          printf("%s\n", root->basket);
          exit(0); // It would respond to Exit and stop the looping of tree
          return root;

      }
      if(root->left != NULL) {
          loop(root->left);
          printf("%s\n", root->basket);
          return root; // This would be ignored
          exit(0); // This doesn't help too
      }

    }

}
```

I used Exit() for debugging because it does what i want but i cant use it because i wont get the result i want

Comment: Why do you have `exit()` in there? What is the code supposed to do anyway? Why are you returning a value?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: There is not even a loop, but recursion.

Comment: @Olaf sorry, I now learnt that it's recursive.

Comment: @Amit I used Exit() for debugging because it does what i want but i cant use it because i wont get the result i want

Comment: Please EDIT THE QUESTION and include an example of the data you're processing, the results you expect, and the results you're getting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct item* loop(struct item *root)
{

    struct item *ret=root; /*if neither right or left, what would be? root or null*/
   if(root != NULL){
      if(root->right != NULL) {
          ret=loop(root->right);
      }else
      if(root->left != NULL) {
          ret=loop(root->left);
      }else{
            printf("%s\n", root->basket); /*it is the last in tree*/
       }

    }
    return ret; /*the last valid item*/

}
```

Comment: Actually , this is also recursive. :\ Just tested it.

Comment: i know it is recursive. so what you are trying to fix?

Comment: i modified the code little bit, hope that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using exit(0) terminates the process meanwhile return just exits from current function. You are making recursive calls. So when you hit exit(0) the processes is stopped which means that it will exit from all your recursive calls. When code reaches return it just returns to previous state in stack. You need something else than return to exit from recursive calls (like other param or some global/static variable).

Hope that I didn't misunderstand your question.